# i am facing this Problem E/catch ===: org.json.JSONException: No value for SorrySignUpFirst

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-volley

I am Building a Project with PHP, MYSQL, java Volley Library
Problem is that it doesn't work all 3 at the same time  getting this error

**E/catch ===: org.json.JSONException: No value for SorrySignUpFirst**

`SorrySignUpFirst,`

`SorrySignUpFirst,`

`LoginPasswordWrong`

**If I comment 2 then run my Emulator its works so how to solve this Problem**

**PHP CODES**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{

    require_once("connection.php");
     $data_array = array();

    $login_email = $_POST['email'];
    $login_email = strip_tags($login_email);
    $login_email = str_replace(' ', '', $login_email); // remove spaces


    $login_password = $_POST['password'];
    $login_password = strip_tags($login_password);
    $email = str_replace(' ', '', $login_password); // remove spaces


    $db_email = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$login_email'");


    if (mysqli_num_rows($db_email) == 0)

    {

          $data_array['SorrySignUpFirst'] = "1";
           echo json_encode($data_array);

        mysqli_close($connection);

    }

    else
    {

       $data = mysqli_fetch_array($db_email);

        if (password_verify($login_password, $data['password']))
        {

    $data_array['LoginSuccessfull'] = "1";
    $data_array['id'] = $data['id'];
    $data_array['email'] = $data['email'];


    echo json_encode($data_array);

            mysqli_close($connection);

        }
        else
        {

             $data_array['LoginPasswordWrong'] = "1";

            echo json_encode($data_array);
            mysqli_close($connection);


        }

    }

}

?>
```

**LoginActivity.java codes**

```
final StringRequest LoginstringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLS.LOGIN_API, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            String SorrySignUpFirst = jsonObject.getString("SorrySignUpFirst");
            String LoginSuccessfull = jsonObject.getString("LoginSuccessfull");
            String LoginPasswordWrong = jsonObject.getString("LoginPasswordWrong");


            if (SorrySignUpFirst.contains("1")) {
                Intent goToHomeScreenIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToHomeScreenIntent);

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Doen't Exist Sign Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

                if (LoginSuccessfull.contains("1")) {

                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                String fname = jsonObject.getString("email");

                Intent goToHomeScreenIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToHomeScreenIntent);

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "id = " + id + "email == " + fname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            if (LoginPasswordWrong.contains("1")) {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

           else {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "if else if Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "catch -- " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("catch === ", e.toString());
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error= 116" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.i("Catch error 116  ====", error.toString());

    }
})



{

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> loginParams = new HashMap<>();
        loginParams.put("email", Email);
        loginParams.put("password", Password);
        return loginParams;
    }


};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(LoginstringRequest);
```

Comment: You need the equivalent of the `isset()` or (PHPised) `jsonObject.getString("SorrySignUpFirst") ?? '0';`

Comment: sir will you elaborate more ?????

Comment: put this `echo json_encode($data_array);` after your `if-else` statement ,also when you get value from your server ,try to check if it `empty` or `not`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no attribute called SorrySignUpFirst on your jsonObject.

Try placing a breakpoint on this line:

```
String SorrySignUpFirst = jsonObject.getString("SorrySignUpFirst");
```

Inspect the jsonObject and check to see whether or not SorrySignUpFirst exists on it.

Comment: i want to say when i use SorrySignUpFirst then other 2 will show error like  No value for LoginSuccessfull and No value for LoginPasswordWrong

Comment: It has Sir { "SorrySignUpFirst": "1", "SignUpSuccessFull": "1", "LoginPasswordWrong": "1" }

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from the Java side?

Comment: 2019-04-26 16:12:38.465 15327-15327/com.example.newmovieproject E/catch ===: org.json.JSONException: No value for SorrySignUpFirst
2019-04-26 16:12:38.544 15327-15327/com.example.newmovieproject E/catch ===: org.json.JSONException: No value for SorrySignUpFirst
2019-04-26 16:12:38.547 15327-15352/com.example.newmovieproject